# Removing hyphen (-) between two words creates empty elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I am trying to get rid of hyphens in words in a list through the below code

```
listA=['End-to-End Encryption']

listmain= '-'.join(listA).split('-')
```

The output I get is

```
['End', '', '', 'to', '', '', 'End', 'Encryption']
```

How do I get rid of unnecessary blank elements created

Ideal output required

```
['End', 'to', 'End', 'Encryption']
```

How to achieve this.

Comment: `listmain = listA[0].replace(' ','-').split('-')`

Comment: I don't think so list allows blank elements, and your code works for me there is no empty elements.

Comment: I have run your code and my output is different than yours. What is your python version?

Comment: @I'L'I This solution worked. str_list = filter(None, str_list). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Split it by multiple separators. By regex.

```
listA = ['End-to-End Encryption']
listmain = re.split(r'\s|-', listA[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job and is dynamic for more than 1 sent in listA

```
listmain = [val.replace("-"," ").split() for val in listA]
```

Eg:

```
listA = ["End-to-End Encryption", "End-to-End Decryption"]
listmain = [val.replace("-"," ").split() for val in listA]
```

O/P:

```
[["End", "to" ,"End", "Encryption"],["End","to","End","Decryption"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works flawlessly:

```
listA=['End-to-End Encryption']
for el in listA:
    str2 = el.split('-')
    print(str2)
```

The Output of this code is:

```
['End', 'to', 'End Encryption']
```